# Is the solution to a question regarding four smaller masses on a rotating hollow sphere accurate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I was doing the question [here](http://sceweb.uhcl.edu/blanford/Y&F10_008.pdf):

> A uniform 8.40-kg spherical shell, 50.0 cm in diameter has four small
>   2.00-kg masses attached to its outer surface and equally spaced around it. This combination is spinning about an axis running through the
>   center of the sphere and two of the small masses (see [figure](http://sceweb.uhcl.edu/blanford/Y&F10_008.pdf)). What friction torque is needed to reduce its angular speed
>   from 75.0 rpm to 50.0 rpm in 30.0 s?

I understand how to get $\alpha$, and how to get $\tau$ from $I$ and $\alpha$. What I do not understand is their computation of the moment of inertia. The question did not provide any information regarding the shapes of the masses, but the solution (which writes $I=\frac{2}{3}MR^2+2mR^2$) seems to assume that the masses are point particles. Thus, the two masses along the rotational axis have a moment of inertia of 0 ($r=0$), and each of the other two masses has a moment of inertia of $I=mr^2 =mR^2$, where $R$ is the radius of the sphere and $r$ is the distance from the axis.

But why are the masses considered to be point particles? I wanted to use the parallel-axis theorem to determine the moment of inertia about the rotational axis; not knowing the shape of the masses made this impossible, since I couldn’t find the moment of inertia about the CM. If I knew $I_{CM}$, then couldn’t I use $I_{axis}=I_{CM}+mR^2$ for the two masses not on the rotational axis and $I_{CM}$ for the two that are? That would make $I_{total}=\frac{2}{3}MR^2+4I_{CM,\:mass}+2mR^2$ Would that not be a better way of solving this problem?

Comment: The diagram suggests that the small masses are in the same plane, but then those which are diagonally opposite are further away than nearest neighbours. If they are really equidistant in 3D then they will occupy the corners of a tetrahedron. But in this case it is impossible to find an axis through the centre while also through 2 of the small masses.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your reasoning. If you knew the inertial moments of the small bodies through their paralelel axes going through the centers of gravity you could use Steiners theorem. But you do not know the diameter of these bodies and you would still have to use the approximation R for the distance of the outer bodies masses axes from the rotational axis. The problem obviously assumes that the extension (diameter) of the small masses is negligible and that they can be approximated as point masses.

Answer (score 0):

The "small" masses have to be considered to be point particles because no information is given about their size or shape. The diagram also suggests that their size is much smaller than the radius of the large sphere.

Yes your solution **is** more accurate, but $I_{CM}$ is not provided in the question, therefore it cannot be part of the answer.

You might also question the thickness of the spherical shell. The formula $\frac23MR^2$ is exact only for an infinitesimally thin shell. But any real shell will have a finite thickness. A more accurate formula is $\frac25M\frac{R^5-r^5}{R^3-r^3}$ where $r$ is the internal radius. However, the fact that no value for $r$ has been given indicates that you should use the approximation $\frac23MR^2$ instead.

Any real axle on which the spherical shell is rotating also has a small but finite MI, and for an accurate result this ought to be taken into account too.

The moral is that all calculations have to stop somewhere. You can never get to the end of making corrections to improve accuracy. Unless it is obvious that a factor has been omitted by error, you should assume that its effect is negligible.